# Как создать библиотеку графического интерфейса для Python?

Tags: python, gui, библиотека

Я хочу создать свою GUI-библиотеку для Python. Но не могу найти ничего на эту тему в интернете. Мне нужно только пример создания окна и например, кнопки. Чтобы понять сам принцип. Далее я разберусь уже сам.

Comment: Под какой операционкой?

Comment: Желательно для Windows

Comment: Тогда посмотрите функции WinAPI - и оконные типа CreateWindowEx, и графические для работы с контекстами, битмапами, рисования

Comment: IT_Master, sorry, вы что серьезно хотите создать свою `GUI-библиотеку` для Python?

Comment: Вы собрались писать ее при этом на самом питоне ? Тогда боюсь с производительностью у нее все будет очень грустно. Подобные библиотеки питона пишутся на C. А значит и вопрос начинает уже звучать "как работать с оконным интерфейсом Windows на C/C++" на эту тему есть масса литературы

Comment: Смотрите, как интересно устроена история. У нас есть многоядерные процессоры и языки, которые позволяют использовать эту мощь. Но они "слишком сложны", и вместо них начинающим программистам подсовывают разные штуки, котрые скрывают от них многопоточность, и у нас есть php и python, которые по своей природе однопоточны. И программисты, развиваясь, мужственно преодолевают те препятствия, которые есть в их инструменте... вместо того, чтобы сменить инструмент.

Comment: Я не хочу менять инструмент и публиковать свою библиотеку. Мне просто интересно попробовать реализовать такой проект. Вообще узнать как это делаеться.

Comment: P.S. Между прочим, Kivy полностью написан на Python.

Comment: Для Windows, вкратце: 1 - знать основы C/C++, чтобы в принципе понимать как работать с функциями WinAPI, 2 - изучить WinAPI (книга Чарльза Петцольда "Программирование для Windows 95" вполне подойдет), 3 - изучить как вызывать сишные функции из Python с помощью ctypes. В целом, я бы сказал, что это слишком обширный вопрос для stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: так как я сам разбирался с этой темой могу посоветовать https://github.com/pygame/pygame  поизучать исходники, в моем случае я пока остановился на самой библитеке, хотя в планах есть реализация на С++ так как Тkinter меня не устраивает ни внешне, не по производительности